# Windows Phone - continuously tracking and ReverseGeocodeQuery

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm using the new Windows Phone 8 Maps and the Maps Toolkit. On each `PositionChanged` event, I set the `UserLocationMarker` to the new position. If the user taps on the `UserLocationMarker`, I will show the map location via `ReverseGeocodeQuery` and set the user location Pushpin to visible. To do this really fast, I execute the `ReverseGeocodeQuery` in the `PositionChanged` event.

My question is, if the users location changed very quickly, it will execute many `ReverseGeocodeQuery`s. Is this a performance issue?

```
private void InitializeGeolocator()
{
    geolocator = new Geolocator();
    geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    geolocator.MovementThreshold = 5;
    geolocator.StatusChanged += geolocator_StatusChanged;
    geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
}

private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        Geoposition geoposition = args.Position;

        this.UserLocationMarker.GeoCoordinate = geoposition.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
        this.UserLocationMarker.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        // execute ReverseGeocodeQuery...
        // set Pushpin
    });
}

private void userLocationMarker_tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    // show user location pushpin...
    UserLocationPushpin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ReverseGeocodeQuery` is called inside the `PositionChanged` event, then yes, this can lead to performance problems.

As a general rule, any asynchronous call in Windows Phone (and Windows 8 / WinRT) usually implies that it may not return a value in a fixed time - it may take 50ms, it may take 5 seconds.

With `ReverseGeocodeQuery`, it makes a network call to Nokia’s servers (geo.nlp.nokia.com) to get the address. And although this call return very quickly when using Wifi or a good 3G connection, this would not be true if you had poor reception.

And although I can understand what you’re trying to do - look up the address in advance so that when a user taps on the `UserLocationMarker`, the address appears instantly - bad network quality could create either a delay or an exception.

My suggestion would be to follow the approach that the built-in Maps app already uses. That is, when a user taps on the `UserLocationMarker`, it displays a “Looking...” label, then does an async address lookup, then updates that label with the address.

Also keep in mind, we don’t know if ReverseGeocodeQuery is rate limited. It doesn’t appear to be, but that might change in future as most other services are - [such as Google’s Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits).

What ever you decide to do, handy tools for testing are...

1. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ([and how to use Fiddler with the WP8 emulator](http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/04/Windows-Phone-8-and-Fiddler.aspx))
2. [Simulation Dashboard for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206953%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (simulate bad network conditions, etc)

Comment: Okay, that's looks like a good way! But if the user moves very quickly and taps on the *UserLocationMarker*, then the Pusphin appears and would stay at the old location. How is this handled by the built-in maps application?

Comment: The built-in Maps app appears to have two pins, `UserLocationMarker` with a `PushPin` behind it. When the user taps on the `UserLocationMarker`, the `PushPin` appears with 'looking...' then loads the address. When the location changes **both** pins move and the address updates. If the user taps elsewhere, the `PushPin` hides agagin. The WP8 emulator has the Maps apps, unlike the WP7 emulator, btw.

Comment: Okay, it seems to me, that the built-in app is using the *PositionChanged* event for location update, or?

Comment: Yes, I think it does something similar. And if a `PositionChanged` event occurs while a previous Geocoding lookup is still in progress, it should get cancelled, then start a new one. `ReverseGeocodeQuery` has an `IsBusy` property and `CancelAsync' method which can be used in this case.